# Facebook customer chat plugin override on top of website

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My website has **Facebook Customer Chat Plugin** from [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin) for 2 months.

But today, it override my website element instead stand behind or display:none.

I think, facebook is trying to add some effect to their facebook chat, and they are using **opacity: 0;** instead of **display: none;**. This makes our customers unable to click on website's elements.

So what can I do with this now. I've removed it temporarily.

[Can not click behind facebook, this is preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk8T6.png)

Here is the demo link : https://laptop8x.com/

Comment: Please share demo link or code sample so i can troubleshoot. Maybe its a z-index issue.

Comment: Here is the demo : https://laptop8x.com/
I don't think so because this issue happen on this day only. 
But thank you for spend time on this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code.

```
.fb_customer_chat_bounce_out {
   z-index: -1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But if i do this, facebook customer chat will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Negative z-index doesnt solve this problem, because initially doesnt have classes.

I tried with this:

```
.fb-customerchat iframe {
    pointer-events: none;
}

iframe.fb_customer_chat_bounce_in {
    pointer-events: inherit;
}

iframe.fb_customer_chat_bounce_out {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This is still not a perfect solution. If I open the customer chat and refresh the page, the chatbox is opened, but I can not catch this state without class. In my opinion, Facebook today caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code in your CSS to move it wherever you wish:

```
.fb_customer_chat_bubble_pop_in {top:20px!important}
```

Good Luck